# How to remove '(size WxH from force-height)' from tmux unusable area?

Tags: tmux

I'm using `set force-height 28` in tmux to create some unusable space.  After setting `force-height` the dimensions are shown in the bottom right corner of the unusable space.  Any way to not show that text?

[image: tmux size WxH from force-height]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be anything in the man page about removing that string.

With a quick glance at the tmux [source code for printing that string](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/d4eeeb5498822d4330f19534f5b25b70589aec1f/screen-redraw.c#L427), it doesn't appear as if there are any switches for disabling it. If you really hate that string, you could edit the source code and recompile tmux for your system.